# Notify user-space about interrupt, sleep otherwise

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, interrupt

As a beginner, I want to know what people think would be the best course of action for the following scenario. I have a driver that handles a rising-edge interrupt on a gpio pin. The driver also has a timer that counts down from 30 seconds, for example, once an interrupt happens.

When an interrupt happens, I want a userspace application to wake up and work until that 30-second timer expires, then go back to sleep. And wait to get notified again. I don't need to worry about occasionally missing an interrupt.

I have the gpio, interrupt and timer all working, I just want to know how I should go about sleeping.

Comment: How does your userspace process interact with the driver?  Do you expose a character device interface to userspace?

Comment: @AndyDalton yes, by a character device

Comment: When you say the application should work for 30s, what does "work" mean? Does it involve, for example, reading from the character device?

Comment: @AndyDalton no, it reads from a separate device thru sysfs. The char driver is in charge of sleeping/waking up

Comment: If the process doesn't interact with the driver, then how will the driver cause the process to sleep?

Comment: @AndyDalton The process interacts with the driver through /dev/ with open(), read(), and close() commands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101199/discussion-between-andy-dalton-and-gabson).

Comment: Check out the [UIO](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.3/driver-api/uio-howto.html) driver ... to quote: _Interrupts are handled by reading from `/dev/uioX`. A blocking **read()** from `/dev/uioX` will return as soon as an interrupt occurs. You can also use **select()** on `/dev/uioX` to wait for an interrupt. The integer value read from `/dev/uioX` represents the total interrupt count. You can use this number to figure out if you missed some interrupts._

Comment: Please see resulting project here:
https://github.com/gteeger/PiScale